# Python module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'to_thread'

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio

From python's asyncio examples:

```
import asyncio
import time
def blocking_io():
    print(f"start blocking_io at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    # Note that time.sleep() can be replaced with any blocking
    # IO-bound operation, such as file operations.
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"blocking_io complete at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def main():
    print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(blocking_io),
        asyncio.sleep(1))

    print(f"finished main at {time.strftime('%X')}")


asyncio.run(main())

# Expected output:
#
# started main at 19:50:53
# start blocking_io at 19:50:53
# blocking_io complete at 19:50:54
# finished main at 19:50:54
```

It is outputting the next error:

```
    asyncio.to_thread(blocking_io),
    AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'to_thread'
```

Has this feature been deprecated? What would be an alternative for threading with asyncio?

Comment: `to_thread` was added in 3.9. For older versions use `run_in_executor`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`to_thread` is only available in python 3.9+, if you are working with python 3.8 or an older version, you can copy the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/threads.py#L12) of it:

```
async def to_thread(func, /, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    func_call = functools.partial(ctx.run, func, *args, **kwargs)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func_call)
```

This method copies the context to the thread(to use the current value of your set [ContextVars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html))

If you don't need that and just want a one liner:

```
await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, blocking_io, arg1, arg2)
```

More info about [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

Answer (score 3):

The top answer didn't help me since was already using python 3.9.7.and continued to get the error

```
File "<conda_path>/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
AttributeError: module 'anyio' has no attribute 'to_thread'
```

I found the issue in my pypi installs where a package was not updating and needed a force update.

```sh
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
```

My requirements.txt contained these libraries so it could be anyone of them that was reinstalled and fixed my problem.

```
moto
uvicorn
fastapi
gunicorn
dnspython
```

Comment: Updating `gunicorn` and `uvicorn` lbraries helped! Thank you