# how to optimise code effectively, how to implement multithreading with asyncio

Tags: python, performance, optimization, python-asyncio

In simple terms, what the script does and what I need your support for. The algorithm runs, it takes more than 10 mins to create all the files. With this, queue consumes the message multiple times. This initiates the algorithm again and creates multilpe files, the script ends up taking too long, sometimes 10-15 minutes depending on how much data is in the file. Do you have any ideas on how to optimise the script so that it runs much faster:

```
   async def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    if msg.content_type != "application/json":
        logging.info("Incorrect content type")
        return
    msg_body = json.loads(msg.get_body().decode("utf-8"))
    cc = msg_body.get("cc")
    job_id = msg_body.get("job_id")

    if cc is None or job_id is None:
        # Missing parameters
        logging.info("Required params are missing from message")
        return
    await update_status(
        job_id=job_id, cc=cc, status="EXECUTING", algorithm=ALGORITHM_NAME
    )

    # Reading input files
    azure_blob_client = AzureContainerClient(container=cc)

    # Files can be read form  API, when flag is_x set on True came from FE
    raw_csv_file = StringIO(
        await get_input_data(
            az_cl=azure_blob_client, name_part="Data", data_type="raw"
        )
    )
    ziajas_list = pd.read_csv(
        raw_csv_file
    )
   
    ziaja_json = ziajas_list.to_json(orient="records", date_format="iso")

    results = json.loads(ziaja_json)
    ziajas = {}
    for ziaja in results:
        ziaja_name = ziaja["carr"]
        if ziaja_name in ziajas:
            ziajas[ziaja_name].append(ziaja)
        else:
            ziajas[ziaja_name] = [ziaja]
        
    current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_date_and_time_string = str(current_date_and_time)
    current_date_and_time_string = current_date_and_time_string.replace(' ', '_')
    ziaja_check_list = []
    ZiajaMapping = await get_parameters(parameters_name=ALGORITHM_NAME)
    all_results = []
    #Read parameter file

    for ziaja_name, ziajas_list in ziajas.items():
        try:
            if ziaja_name not in ziaja_check_list:
                user_list = get_ziaja_user_list(ziaja_name, ZiajaMapping)
                timezone = get_cc_details_timezone(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                cc_ID = get_cc_details_ccID(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                text_to_include = get_cc_details_text_to_include(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                admins = get_admins(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                meta_data = {
                "distribution": {
                    "method": "email",
                    "users": user_list,
                    "ccID": cc_ID,
                    "admin": admins
                },
                "subject": f"update for {timezone}",
                "header": {
                    "include": True, 
                    "apply_css": True
                },
                "handling": {
                    "message_style": "etxt", 
                    "title": "Lot update", 
                    "std_msg": "txt", 
                    "personalized_msg": text_to_include
                },  
                "footer": {
                    "include": True,
                    "footer_msg": "that algorithm"
                },
                "signature": {
                    "inclue": True,
                    "signature_text": "Team"
                },
                "attachments": {
                    "include": True,
                    "attachment_bytes": "base64string",
                    "attach_csv": True
                }, 
                "algorithm": {},
                "cc": {}
                }
                all_results.append(store_results(
                    result=ziajas_list,
                    cc=cc,
                    job_id=ziaja_name + "_" + current_date_and_time_string,
                    algorithm_name=ALGORITHM_NAME,
                    meta=meta_data,
                ))
                ziaja_check_list.append(ziaja_name)
        
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)

    return await asyncio.gather(*all_results)
```

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio` eventloop runs in a single thread and executes all callbacks and tasks whithin itself. While a task is running no other task can run at the same time. When the task running executes an `await` expresion the running task gets suspended and the other task is executed.

So, a long-term tasks (such as file operations) will block the event loop unitil the task reaches an `await` (or gets done). To prevent this, `asycio` provides a high-level function to asynchronously run a function in a separate thread:

```
asyncio.to_thread(func, /, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
import time
import asyncio

def blockingTask():
    print(f"start blockingTask at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"blockingTask complete at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def task1():
    print(f"started task1 at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    for i in range(10):
        print(f'Task {i+1}/10')
        time.sleep(1)
    print(f"task1 complete at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def main():
    print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await asyncio.gather(
        to_thread(blockingTask),
        task1())
    print(f"finished main at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())

##### Output:
# blockingTask complete at 12:41:57
# task1 complete at 12:41:58
# finished main at 12:41:58
```

As you can see these two taks use `time.sleep()` wich provokes the thread to freeze. Even blocking the thread the two tasks get finished at the same time, this because are running in different threads

Notes:

1. `to_thread` is only available in python 3.9+
2. > Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking the event loop for the full duration of the function call.
3. If you are working with an older version, you can declare the function `to_thread` by yourself. See the accepted answer to this question:
   [Python module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'to_thread'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68523752/python-module-asyncio-has-no-attribute-to-thread) (I already tested it and worked). If you declare the function by yourself make sure to import `contextvars` and `functools`.
4. Note that when you call `to_thread(blockingTask)` the function wrapped doesn't have brackets

Comment: Do you have any other ideas unfortunately I do not have the option to upgrade to version 3.9, I only have version 3.8 available on the server. I would like to change this piece of code so that it can be executed at the same time, any idea ?

Comment: user_list = get_ziaja_user_list(ziaja_name, ZiajaMapping)
                timezone = get_cc_details_timezone(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                cc_ID = get_cc_details_ccID(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                text_to_include = get_cc_details_text_to_include(cc, ZiajaMapping)
                admins = get_admins(cc, ZiajaMapping)

Comment: I updated my answer. Check point 3. That must work